# Select from 3 tables with foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

Need to display next: all fNAME and lNAME from table username that have position of "Admin" from location "3RD Floor", with IN clause

```
create table company 
(
    CODE_COMPANY char(30),
    NAME_COMPANY varchar2(30) not null,
    MAIL_COMPANY varchar2(30) null,

    constraint PK_CODE_COMPANY primary key (CODE_COMPANY),
);

create table USERNAME 
(
    NAME_USERNAME varchar2(30),
    USER_LOCATION number,
    fNAME varchar2 (30) not null,
    lNAME varchar2 (30) not null,
    PHONE_USER char(13) null,
    USER_POSITION varchar2 (30),
    check (USER_POSITION in('Admin', 'Superadmin', 'Technician', 'Student')),

    constraint PK_NAME_USERNAME primary key (NAME_USERNAME),
    constraint FK_USER_LOCATION foreign key (USER_LOCATION) references uLOCATION (LOCATION)
);

create table uLOCATION 
(
    LOCATION number,
    CODE_COMPANY char(30),
    NAME_LOCATION varchar2(30) not null,
    FLOOR_LOCATION varchar2(10),
    check (FLOOR_LOCATION in ('MAIN_FLOOR', '1ST FLOOR', '2ND FLOOR', '3RD FLOOR')),

    constraint PK_LOCATION primary key (LOCATION),
    constraint FK_CODE_COMPANY_L foreign key (CODE_COMPANY) references company (CODE_COMPANY),
);
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT U.fName, U.lName
FROM   USERNAME AS U
WHERE  U.USER_POSITION = 'Admin'
       AND
       U.USER_LOCATION IN (
                          SELECT L.LOCATION 
                          FROM   uLOCATION AS L
                          WHERE  L.FLOOR_LOCATION = '3RD FLOOR'
                          );
```

Comment: That one is good, can you also help, do the same selection of USER_POSITION that work for NAME_COMPANY = 'ABC'?

Comment: @don'tknownothing . . .This answers the question that you asked.  It is a correct and you should accept it.  If you have another question, you should ask it as a *new* question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

select fName, lName
from USERNAME, uLOCATION, COMPANY
where uLOCATION.LOCATION = USERNAME.USER_LOCATION and COMPANY.CODE_COMPANY = uLOCATION.CODE_COMPANY;

But how to specify, that I need user Admin from NAME_COMPANY ABC?
how to add 2 more WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0):

Slight modifying SQLRaptor's answer for NAME_COMPANY:

```
SELECT U.fName, U.lName
FROM   USERNAME AS U
WHERE  U.USER_POSITION = 'Admin'
       AND
       U.USER_LOCATION IN (
                          SELECT L.LOCATION 
                          FROM   uLOCATION AS L JOIN COMPANY AS C
                              ON L.CODE_COMPANY=C.CODE_COMPANY
                          WHERE  L.FLOOR_LOCATION = '3RD FLOOR' AND C.NAME_COMPANY = 'ABC'
                          );
```